# Strange C++ operator syntax in atlsafe.h

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

In [atlsafe.h](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3xzbsee8.aspx) there is some strange operator syntax I am not familiar with:

```
operator LPSAFEARRAY() throw()
{
    return m_psa; 
}
```

Could someone please explain how this function works and provide an example of how it is used? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[operator LPSAFEARRAY()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wwc26249.aspx) is a [type conversion operator](http://people.cs.vt.edu/kafura/cs2704/op.overloading3.html) that allows a class to be automatically (implicitly) converted to the type named in the operator (LPSAFEARRAY).

Answer (score 1):

This is a conversion operator. It allows objects of type `CComSafeArray<T>` to be implicitly converted to `LPSAFEARRAY`.

Example:

```
CComSafeArray<int> array(10);
//Implicitly calls `array.operator LPSAFEARRAY()` to construct a LPSAFEARRAY
//from `array`
LPSAFEARRAY underlying_array(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a [conversion operator](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C++_Programming/Operators/Operator_Overloading#Conversion_operators). At the end [`throw()`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fcplr156.htm) means that the function won't throw any exception.

An example:

```
class String
{
public:
  String( const char * str )
    : buffer(0)
  {
    if ( ( str != 0 ) && ( str[0] != '\0' ) )
    {
      this->buffer = new char[ strlen(str) + 1 ];
      strcpy( this->buffer, str );
    }
  };
  ~String( void )
  {
    if ( this->buffer != 0 )
    {
      delete [] this->buffer;
      this->buffer = 0;
    }
  };
  operator const char * (void) { return this->buffer; };
private:
  char * buffer;
};

String one("1"), two("2");
if ( strcmp(one,two) == 0 )
{
  // works fine
}
```